# Plugin not loading in Rhapsody

Tags: java, rhapsody

I have a java plugin for Rhapsody but somehow its not loading
Code sample:

```
IRPApplication app = null;
public class ProjectHistory extends RPUserPlugin{
@Override
public void RhpPluginInit(final IRPApplication rpyApplication) {
app = rpyApplication;
}
}
```

The helper file is like:

```
#REM: Definition of the plug-in
name16=Compare...
#REM: the class that implements Rhapsody's callbacks
JavaMainClass16=com.example.rhy.ProjectHistory
#REM: Class paths your application use
JavaClassPath16=./plugins/profile.jar;./plugins/GenericLib.jar;./plugins/java_lib/api.jar
#REM: Tells Rhapsody that this helper is actually a plug-in
isPlugin16=1
isVisible16=1

#REM: Definition of the pup-up menu that trigger the plugin
name17=Compare...
#REM: Tells Rhapsody that this helper actually invokes a plug-in
isPluginCommand17=1
#REM: The command is actually the plug-in name
command17=Compare...
#REM: to create a pop-up menu item on OMDs
applicableTo17=Package
isVisible17=1
```

But the plugin is not even loading. There is no error in log file

Rhapsody version is 8.1.4 and Java version used for compilation is 1.8

Comment: I got the solution. As I was using external library the Rhapsody was unable to load it somehow as I was calling the classes of the external library in the main class. So I removed the code and created another class to call external classes. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would enable logging for the plugins.
This can be done in the rhapsody.ini file, in the [General] section add the line:

JavaAPILogFile=c:\api_log.txt

You can choose another path for the logfile, if you want.
In the logfile you will find all output done while loading the plugins, 
a good starting point is start searching for exception or for your plugins name.

BTW did you increased the number of items in the HEP-File you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Frank's advice, I would add that your plugin (as presented here) should not even compile as you have your "app" variable being defined BEFORE your class definition.  You need to move that down inside the class.  Also, I've had better luck with using fully qualified pathnames in the .hep files when referring to .jar files that contain plugins.  Finally, the actual execution of your plugin logic happens in the RhpPluginInvokeItem() method so be sure you provide that.  In fact, be sure you provide over-ridden methods for all methods from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

some potential or clear issues:

- supported java version from rhapsody as of today (rhapsody 8.2.1) is Java 7 SDK (Java 8 is not
  supported)
- if you extend RhpPluginInit then you have a already method to
  override: void RhpPluginInit(IRPApplication rpyApplication), so, you have your
  Application already.

  - and as mentioned in comments above, IRPApplication shall not
    be defined outside the class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Rhapsody fails to register dlls in the registry during Rhapsody installation. As a result plugins cannot be loaded correctly. To solve this you need to manually register rhaposodyserver.dll by following below instructions:

> - Open a Command Prompt as Administrator (right-click cmd.exe and choose ‘Run as Administrator’).
> - CD to the installation directory of the Rhapsody.
> - Enter the command: **regsvr32.exe rhapsodyserver.dll**

You will receive a message that shows registration was successful.
You need to restart the system after this. Hope this helps.

[Reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22003108)